# autocomplete jQuery.noConflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I want to add a new autocomplete input to an existing page, that already uses a bundled version of jQuery. Therefore I need to use `jQuery.noConflict()`.

Outside of this page my code works fine, but on the existing page I don't know how to get it to work.

I always get an Error `$ (...).autocomplete is not a function`.

Here the code I use:

```
// .....code from existing page with already loaded jQuery script 

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    /* Make the AJAX request once for the source array: */
    $.getJSON("./mapdata/get_list_json.php", function (data) {
        $("#parzelle").autocomplete({
            minLength: 3,`enter code here`
            source: data,
            dataType: "json",
            select: function(event, ui) {
        // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
        event.preventDefault();
        // manually update the textbox and hidden field
        $(this).val(ui.item.label);
        $("#gid").val(ui.item.value);
        }
        });
    });   
});
```

Comment: OK, I've changed the order of the loaded script:  `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">  // .....code from existing page with already loaded jQuery script ` now the autocomple works with the submitted code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I did also e few changings to the code.
So here is how I get it to work:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

// .....code from existing page with already loaded jQuery script 

$J = jQuery.noConflict();
$J( document ).ready(function( $J ) {
//$(function () {
    /* Make the AJAX request once for the source array: */
    $J.getJSON("./mapdata/get_parzellen_list_json.php", function (data) {
        $J("#parzelle").autocomplete({
            minLength: 3,
            source: data,
            dataType: "json",
            select: function(event, ui) {
        // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
        event.preventDefault();
        // manually update the textbox and hidden field
        $J(this).val(ui.item.label);
        $J("#gid").val(ui.item.value);
        }
        });
    });   
});
```